# AngularJS parsing recursive JSON into object array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, angularjs, spring-boot

I have been having trouble with AngularJS 1.7 and getting objects from backend for filtering purposes. Namely, I'm receiving a JSON comprised of the same objects, but some are children of others, such as this:

```
[
    {
        "id":2,
        "type":"CORP",
        "description":"A-corpus",
        "children": [
            {
                "id":3,
                "type":"FLOOR",
                "description":"1st floor",
                "children":[]} ]
             }
         ]
     }
]
```

These objects are all of the type Place. I do not know the depth of the JSON beforehand and have to go through it recursively to get a list of all the places. For that I created a corresponding object called place.ts:

```
export class Place {
  constructor(
    public id: Number,
    public type: String,
    public description: String,
    public children: Array<Place>) {}
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class placeAdapter implements Adapter<Place> {
  adapt(item: any): Place {
    return new Place(
      item.id,
      item.type,
      item.description,
      item.children
    );
  }
}
```

where the adapter is a design pattern from [Consuming APIs in Angular: The Model-Adapter Pattern](https://blog.florimond.dev/consuming-apis-in-angular-the-model-adapter-pattern), which works fine with receiving other items from the backend. In addition, I have the service typescript called place.service.ts:

```
export class PlaceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private adapter: placeAdapter) {}

  public query(): Observable<Place[]> {
    return this.http.get('api/places').pipe(
      map((data:any[]) => {
        console.log("place by type:" + data);
        return data.map(item => this.adapter.adapt(item));
      }));
  }
```

This design did read some nested items from other endpoints but goes into an endless loop when I try to receive these objects. The objects it outputs to console repeatedly are:

> place by type:[object Object],[object Object]

even if I give it a JSON with no children places. IntelliJ shows me endless requests for the same places and their children. No matter how many nested items the JSON has, the parsing runs into a loop and I can't get anything, because the loop causes the whole application to run too slowly.

How is parsing of such recursive JSON-s into object arrays done in AngularJS using the best practices?

Comment: That adaptor pattern looks like a convoluted way of applying a simple pure function, no need to dependency inject an adaptor when you can just import a pure function and use it in a map. I would not allow that pattern to pollute my project.

Comment: You might be right, but this is not the source of the problem. However, I think I may have found it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The objects did turn out usable and the loop was not a fault with the code I posted. It was the fault with an Angular component [ng-multiselect-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown), which I was trying to get the data for (it called out the method that queried the place list). After a  little research, it turned out the component didn't support dynamic content and it or Angular itself kept repeating the GET-request because of that.

After some workarounds, the component now accepts dynamic content and I can access the place objects just fine with the code I posted before.